# ¿como hacer que "mpv" me lo reconozca los controles en segundo plano?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash 
clear  
echo 
echo "========== Reproductor clasic ========="  
echo
echo "---[Ejemplos de los controles]---"
echo " Play/Reanudar [P] | Siguiente [Enter] | Volum [9] - Volum + [0]" #<--- Los Controles  que suelo usar yo 
echo 
mpv https://youtu.be/MX_oB4O3CDk  &> /dev/null
```

**Cuándo no le pongo en segundo plano me reproduce ala perfección y los controles me funciona. Y cuando reproduce la música en segundo plano me reproduce pero no me reconoce los controles** `uso termux`